# Load data from excel file to MySQL database?

Tags: pentaho

I have an Excel file containing raw data without primary keys and with many fields that don't exist in my MySQL database tables. How do I perform an ETL (in Pentaho Kettle) that can:

```
1. Retrieve the necessary columns
2. Edit and attach an ID_KEY column 
3. Generate and increment id_key
4. Inject all data into my MySQL database tables
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

1. Use "Microsoft Excel Input" Step: Read the excel file which is your source data.
2. Next, use "[Select Values](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Select+Values)" step to edit the input data in the format you need.
3. In the next hop, use "[Add Sequence](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Add+sequence)" Step to generate an unique key for every input rows.
4. Finally use a "Table Output" Step with the MySQL database credentials to upload your data.

Hope it helps :)